# (actionscript 3) How can I create virtual keys that simulate specific keyboard inputs

Tags: actionscript-3

i'm new to AS3 (and to Stack as well), so I actually wanted to get an old swf game into apk, I did not have the source so I just embedded it into a AS3 fla file.
Luckly the game works fine, but I have no buttons.
I don't have any contact with the game source code so I just want to simulate several keys (A,Z,Q,W,S,C,V...)
TLDR : How can I make virtual buttons (aka gamepad) for an embedded flash game in an APK?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please specify the problem. Are you asking how to design buttons with Flash?

Comment: More than that, I want to know how I can make a buttons (1) and I want to know how I can simulate keyboard event buttons like (key_up, key_down_,"Z","E"...)

Comment: I think you should look at `dispatchEvent()` method in `flash.events.IEventDispatcher` interface. All top level objects inherit that and can dispatch events to the display list, starting with `stage`. You'll also need to read how to create a custom `Event` object in order to be able to properly dispatch an event of a letter pressed on a keyboard. However this can raise some security issues with latest Flash players, as this behavior can be considered malicious.

Comment: I actually searched for days about how to do that, none was helpful and every code is full of errors I don't know why, is there a sample fla file for this?

Comment: @RayanEru use the `@` symbol to reply to specific people, otherwise only the first commenter gets notified of your comment replies. _"Luckly the game works fine"_ okay so what's the first button you need to press? Is it spacebar to the game? What happens when you add (to the swf instance) an event listener for spacebar keypress?

Comment: @VC.One I wanna add arrow keys, I followed several tutorials but none of them work